# The following function is null this.ParentForm, any suggestions?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

```
((food)this.ParentForm).getlistoffood();
```

it calls a method `getlistoffood` from food.cs file. But it `this.ParentForm` is null.

Comment: why are you casting partent form to food?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ParentForm` is only available given that you had set it previously. Have you?

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform(v=vs.110).aspx